Flutter camera plugin not initializing on iOS iPhone XR device
Flutter camera plugin. Not initialise controller on iOS iPhone XR device
I have a camera widget in my Flutter application, and it initializes successfully on Android devices. However, on an iPhone XR running iOS, the camera initialization either doesn’t happen or has a significant delay. The code for my camera widget is as follows:
Here is your code properly formatted with 4 spaces indentation:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../images/cached_image.dart';
import '../models/image.dart';
import '../theme/extensions/colors.dart';
import 'camera_controls.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
    const Camera({
        super.key,
    });

    @override
    State<Camera> createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver, TickerProviderStateMixin {
    CameraController? _controller;
    XFile? _imageFile;
    final bool _enableAudio = false;
    double _minAvailableZoom = 1;
    double _maxAvailableZoom = 1;
    double _currentScale = 1;
    double _baseScale = 1;

    // Counting pointers (number of user fingers on screen)
    int _pointers = 0;
    var _cameras = <CameraDescription>[];

    bool get _controllerIsAvailable => _controller != null;

    bool get _isInitialized =>
        _controllerIsAvailable && _controller!.value.isInitialized;

    bool get _flashIsOff =>
        _controllerIsAvailable && _controller!.value.flashMode == FlashMode.off;

    bool get _isBackCamera =>
        _controllerIsAvailable &&
        _controller!.description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
            SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
                const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                    statusBarColor: Colors.black,
                ),
            );

            await _startCamera();
        });
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
            await _controller?.dispose();
            SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
                const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
            );
        });

        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        final cameraController = _controller;

        // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
        if (_controllerIsAvailable && !cameraController!.value.isInitialized) {
            return;
        }

        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
            if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
                await cameraController?.dispose();
            } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
                await _initializeCameraController(cameraController!.description);
            }
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => Stack(
        children: [
            if (_isInitialized)
                Positioned.fill(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: Listener(
                            onPointerDown: (_) => _pointers++,
                            onPointerUp: (_) => _pointers--,
                            child: CameraPreview(
                                _controller!,
                                child: LayoutBuilder(
                                    builder: (context, constraints) => GestureDetector(
                                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                                        onScaleStart: _handleScaleStart,
                                        onScaleUpdate: _handleScaleUpdate,
                                        onTapDown: (details) async => onViewFinderTap(
                                            details,
                                            constraints,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            if (_imageFile != null)
                Positioned.fill(
                    child: CachedImage(
                        image: LocalImageVm(url: _imageFile!.path),
                    ),
                ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Row(
                        children: [
                            const SizedBox(width: 8),
                            if (_imageFile == null || _isBackCamera)
                                IconButton(
                                    color: context.colorsTheme.background,
                                    icon: Icon(
                                        _flashIsOff ? Icons.flash_off : Icons.flash_on,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                        await _toggleFlashlight();
                                    },
                                ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: CameraControls(
                    onPressedResetImage: _imageFile != null
                        ? _resetImageFile
                        : () async => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    onPressedTakePicture:
                        _imageFile == null ? _onPressedTakePicture : null,
                    onPressedSwitchCamera: _imageFile != null
                        ? () async {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(_imageFile);
                        }
                        : () async {
                            await onNewCameraSelected();
                        },
                ),
            ),
        ],
    );

    Future<void> _startCamera() async {
        _cameras = await availableCameras();

        if (_cameras.isNotEmpty) {
            await _initializeCameraController(_cameras[0]);
        }
    }

    void _handleScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
        _baseScale = _currentScale;
    }

    Future<void> _handleScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) async {
        // When there are not exactly two fingers on screen don't scale
        if (_pointers != 2) {
            return;
        }

        _currentScale = (_baseScale * details.scale)
            .clamp(_minAvailableZoom, _maxAvailableZoom);

        await _controller!.setZoomLevel(_currentScale);
    }

    Future<void> _resetImageFile() async {
        setState(() {
            _imageFile = null;
        });
    }

    Future<void> _toggleFlashlight() async {
        try {
            await _controller!.setFlashMode(
                _controller!.value.flashMode == FlashMode.off
                    ? FlashMode.torch
                    : FlashMode.off,
            );
        } on CameraException catch (e) {
            _showCameraException(e);
        }
    }

    Future<void> onViewFinderTap(
        TapDownDetails details,
        BoxConstraints constraints,
    ) async {
        final cameraController = _controller;

        final offset = Offset(
            details.localPosition.dx / constraints.maxWidth,
            details.localPosition.dy / constraints.maxHeight,
        );
        await cameraController!.setExposurePoint(offset);
        await cameraController.setFocusPoint(offset);
    }

    Future<void> onNewCameraSelected() async {
        final description = !_isBackCamera ? _cameras[0] : _cameras[1];

        return _controller!.setDescription(description);
    }

    Future<void> _initializeCameraController(
        CameraDescription cameraDescription,
    ) async {
        await _controller?.dispose();
        _controller = CameraController(
            cameraDescription,
            ResolutionPreset.max,
            enableAudio: _enableAudio,
            imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
        );

        await _controller!.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);

        _controller!.addListener(() {
            if (mounted) {
                setState(() {});
            }

            if (_controller!.value.hasError) {
                throw Exception('Camera error ${_controller!.value.errorDescription}');
            }
        });
        try {
            await _controller!.initialize();

            await _controller!
                .getMaxZoomLevel()
                .then((value) => _maxAvailableZoom = value);
            await _controller!
                .getMinZoomLevel()
                .then((value) => _minAvailableZoom = value);
        } on CameraException catch (e) {
            _showCameraException(e);
        }

        if (mounted) {
            setState(() {});
        }
    }

    Future<void> _onPressedTakePicture() async {
        final file = await takePicture();

        if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
                _imageFile = file;
            });
        }

        // await onPausePreview();
    }

    Future<void> setFlashMode(FlashMode mode) async {
        try {
            await _controller!.setFlashMode(mode);
        } on CameraException catch (e) {
            _showCameraException(e);
        }
    }

    Future<XFile?> takePicture() async {
        final cameraController = _controller;
        if (!cameraController!.value.isInitialized) {
            throw Exception('Error: select a camera first.');
        }

        if (cameraController.value.isTakingPicture) {
            // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
            return null;
        }

        try {
            final file = await cameraController.takePicture();

            return file;
        } on CameraException catch (e) {
            _showCameraException(e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
        throw Exception('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
    }
}

I’ve tried different options for initialization and added variables to check isInitialised, but despite this, the controller does not initialize on iOS.
flutter doctor output:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-UA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Hindenburg. Ensure the device is
      unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area
      network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] Network resources


Hi were you able to resolve this, I am having the same error on iOS, it crashes on camera initialization and throws this error "Error -11814 Cannot Record".

Hello, @PeterAkwa
I have not. Switched to image_picker link. It solved my issue

Oh I see, mine was solved by picking my camera description from the system's available cameras rather than creating another camera description. But I don't think it should be the same case as yours since you are getting the available cameras and selecting the one on index 0
